# Handling and Saving radio values in Laravel (5.4)\Collective forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, radio-button

I am storing the radio button values to database but getting the following error, I want to save either yes or no to the database

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'aware_raise_male' doesn't
>   have a default value

**This is my radio button form**

```
{!! Form::radio('aware_raise_male', 'Y',  (old ('aware_raise_male') == 'Y' ))!!} Yes
{!! Form::radio('aware_raise_male', 'N',  (old ('aware_raise_male') == 'N' ))!!} No
```

**Save controller**

```
 $input->aware_raise_male = $request->get('aware_raise_male')? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: its an mysql error .set default value for field in phpmyadmin or in your migration.what is condition you have checked using conditional operator.

Comment: `$input->aware_raise_male = $request->has('aware_raise_male')? 'Y' : 'N';`

Comment: @Sohel0415 still same error

Comment: which line you are having the error?? show us complete controller code and your schema.

Comment: @RamKesavan Thanks Working, set a default value

Comment: Glad the issue is fixed.@EriGits